# Display Issues with Linear Gradient and React-Native-Deck-Swiper on react native. My cards are cropped on the right side

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, swipe, display

I'm looking to have a swipe on cards ('tinder like') on my projects, but i need to have a gradient as a background color. It looks like the expo linear gradient and @AlexBrilliant React-Native-Deck-Swiper aren't compatible. The cards are on the right of the display, half-cropped.
I found that the issue is located around the styling of the linear gradient because if we delete `alignItems:'center'` from the styling, the card are well centered in the middle but there is no Linear Gradient.

My app on github : https://github.com/Maxime-Lapeyrere/swipetest.git

Here is what i've tried :

````
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import Swiper from 'react-native-deck-swiper'
import { color } from 'react-native-reanimated';
import { Colors } from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
import { Button, Input, ButtonGroup } from "react-native-elements";


const data = [
 {id: 'blablabla',
 price:'20€',
 name:'Maxime',
 image:'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/d8/1c/ae/d81caed831c47cdd329baf6dc304cbcb.jpg'
 },
 {id: 'blobloblo',
 price:'30€',
 name:'Tom',
 image:'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/a0/ef/35/a0ef352c96992ef65c5e8e65c3614807.jpg'
 },
 {id: 'kdahedjaeh',
 price:'450€',
 name:'audrie',
 image:'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/f9/a9/1d/f9a91daa7ec59be23274f596957edfef.jpg'
 },
 {id: 'feaefe',
 price:'600€',
 name:'juliette',
 image:'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/e0/f0/15/e0f0158abc9203386739cd9789d0a585.jpg'
 },
]

const colors = {
 red : '#C93028',
 blue: '#28A7C9',
 grey: '#777777',
 black: '#000000',
 white: '#FFFFFF'
}
export default function App() {
 const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)



 const onSwiped = () => {
   setIndex((index+1)%data.length)
 }

 const Swiperz = () =>{
   return(
<View style={styles.container}>
     <Swiper
       cards={data}
       cardIndex={index}
       renderCard={(card) => <Card card={card}/>}
       onSwiped= {onSwiped}
       stackSize={4}
       stackScale={10}
       stackSeparation={30}
       disableTopSwipe
       disableBottomSwipe
       animateOverlayLabelsOpacity
       animateCardOpacity
       overlayLabels= {{}}
       overlayLabelStyle={{
         
         left:{title:'Nope',
           style: {
             backgroundColor:colors.red,
             color: colors.white,
             fontSize: 12
           },
           wrapper: {
             flexDirection:'column',
             alignItems:'flex-end',
             justifyContent:'flex-start',
           },
         },
         right:{
           title: 'Like',
           label: {
             backgroundColor:colors.blue,
             color: colors.white,
             fontSize: 12
           },
           wrapper: {
             flexDirection:'column',
             alignItems:'flex-end',
             justifyContent:'flex-start',
           },
         }
       }}
     >
     </Swiper>
     <StatusBar style="auto" />
   </View>
 )}
 const Card = ({card}) => (
   <View style={{
     height:400,
     borderRadius:8,
     shadowRadius:25,
     shadowOpacity:0.08,
     shadowColor:colors.black,
     shadowOffset:{width:0,height:0},
     justifyContent:'center',
     alignItems:'center',
     backgroundColor: colors.white
   }} 
   >
     <Image source={{uri: card.image}} style={{
       width:160,
       height:100,
       flex:1,
       resizeMode:'contain'}}
       />
     <Text style={{height:30, color:'black'}}>{card.name}</Text>
   </View>
 )


 return (
   <LinearGradient
   style={{ flex: 1, alignItems:'center' }}
   // Background Linear Gradient
   colors={["rgba(255,188,62,1)", "rgba(255,170,63,1)", "rgba(255,67,67,1)"]}
   locations={[0, 0.7, 1]}
   >
     <Swiperz/>
   
   </LinearGradient>
 );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
   flex: 1,
   backgroundColor: colors.white,
   alignItems: 'center',
   justifyContent: 'center',
 },
 card:{
   height:400,
   borderRadius:8,
   shadowRadius:25,
   shadowOpacity:0.08,
   shadowColor:colors.black,
   shadowOffset:{width:0,height:0},
   justifyContent:'center',
   alignItems:'center',
   backgroundColor: colors.white

 },
 cardImage:{
   width:160,
   height:100,
   flex:1,
   resizeMode:'contain'
 }
});```

and this is what i got: [screen of the app][1]


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHXU8.jpg

I thank you in advance for your help !!! :D
````